# Trigger a js function with parameter from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

C# Trigger a js function with parameter from code behind.
I have the following code:

C#:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptManager1", String.Format(@"ShowHideMessageBlock('{0}')", @"#successMsg"), true);
```

js:

```
function ShowHideMessageBlock(xid) {
    var c = xid;
    console.log(c);

    $(c).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
```

When I open the console window I get the following message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The rendered function is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
ShowHideMessageBlock('#successMsg')Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, {"associatedUpdatePanelId":null,"displayAfter":500,"dynamicLayout":true}, null, null, $get("updateProgress"));
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Can somebody help me with this issue. (It worked in the past) maybe I have changed/broken something and it is not working anymore.

Comment: Where is that `Sys.Application.add_init` stuff coming from?  Also, I think `ShowHideMessageBlock()` should end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a semi-colon to the end of your `String.Format` call.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptManager1", 
    String.Format(@"ShowHideMessageBlock('{0}');", @"#successMsg"), true);
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked.
It has been a long day.
How did I not see that

Comment: @Babulaas Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes ;)

Comment: Thanks much! I was breaking my head to see what went wrong but this missing semicolon fixed it all in 2020 as well :-)